# ggplot2, making a legend for an arranged grid of histograms

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, legend

I have an issue with creating a legend for a histogram. I want to make a grid of histograms with a common legend. I have two issues.

1. Each histogram has a geom-vline showing a mean while the histogram shows all values. I want to make a legend which shows the colour of the geom_vline and the default grey fill of the histogram. I do not seem to be able to do this as to make a legend for fill you seem to need to have histograms split by a factor. Nor can I make a legend for the histogram using scale_colour_manual(). Similarly, I can't make a legend for the vline using scale_fill_manual()
2. I want to be able to centre the legend under the arranged histograms.

below is the code and the output showing my histograms adapted for the iris dataset

```
library(ggplot2)
library(mosaic)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
data("iris")

    setosaHistogram <-ggplot(data=iris)+geom_histogram(mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,color='Petal Histogram'))+xlab('Petal Length') +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold",hjust = 0.5),legend.position="none") +
      ggtitle(paste("Setosa"))+
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(iris[iris$Species=='setosa','Petal.Length']), color = "Species Mean"),linetype=2)+ 
      scale_fill_manual(name = 'Legend',values=C("Petal Histogram"='grey','Species Mean' ="red"))

    versicolorHistogram <-ggplot(data=iris)+geom_histogram(mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,color='Petal Histogram'))+xlab('Petal Length') +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold",hjust = 0.5),legend.position="none") +
      ggtitle(paste("Versicolor"))+
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(iris[iris$Species=='versicolor','Petal.Length']), color = "Species Mean"),linetype=2)+ 
      scale_fill_manual(name = 'Legend',values=C("Petal Histogram"='grey','Species Mean' ="red"))

    virginicaHistogram <-ggplot(data=iris)+geom_histogram(mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,color='Petal Histogram'))+xlab('Petal Length') +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold",hjust = 0.5),legend.position="none") +
      ggtitle(paste("Virginica"))+
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(iris[iris$Species=='virginica','Petal.Length']), color = "Species Mean"),linetype=2)+ 
      scale_fill_manual(name = 'Legend',values=C("Petal Histogram"='grey','Species Mean' ="red"))

    g <- ggplotGrob(setosaHistogram + 
                      theme(legend.position = 'bottom'))$grobs
    #> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
    legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]

    arrangedPlots<-grid.arrange(setosaHistogram,versicolorHistogram,virginicaHistogram,legend,ncol=3, nrow=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: to center the legend I would look into the `layout_matrix` of `grid.arrange` (also in `arrange.grob`)

Comment: `plot_grid` from the cowplot package is another option. It also has the function `get_legend`, which extracts the legend for you.

Comment: Hello L.Zin, I apologise for using local data. I have redone it using the iris dataset, please see the reprex below

Comment: The question has been edited to show the reprex with reproducible data. Thank you for the advice so far